# Bluemix Python App Start unsuccessful

Tags: python, error-handling, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm trying to deploy a Python app i found in a tutorial, but it fails to start.

This is the error i get:
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 failing
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful

This is the app:

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from os import environ
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3

visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3(VisualRecognitionV3.latest_version,  api_key='myapikey')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), 'hearts.zip'), 'rb') as hearts, \
  open(join(dirname(__file__), 'diamonds.zip'), 'rb') as diamonds, \
  open(join(dirname(__file__), 'clubs.zip'), 'rb') as clubs, \
  open(join(dirname(__file__), 'spades.zip'), 'rb') as spades :
print "Uploading files..."
print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.create_classifier('Suits', \
  hearts_positive_examples=hearts, \
  diamonds_positive_examples=diamonds, \
  clubs_positive_examples=clubs, \
  spades_positive_examples=spades), indent=2))
```

Logs:

API/1App instance exited with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af", "version"=>"948e02de-d579-4058-8e89-8573af7ca886", "instance"=>"2f471496fee143cea8e95eb16a05c9e6", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to start", "crash_timestamp"=>1479457233}2016-11-18T10:20:33.805+0200
API/1App instance exited with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af", "version"=>"948e02de-d579-4058-8e89-8573af7ca886", "instance"=>"2f471496fee143cea8e95eb16a05c9e6", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1479457233}2016-11-18T10:20:33.805+0200
DEA/154Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af2016-11-18T10:20:26.727+0200
API/4App instance exited with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af", "version"=>"948e02de-d579-4058-8e89-8573af7ca886", "instance"=>"59b39b134dc347aa8cca9cf93f28ea35", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1479457126}2016-11-18T10:18:46.849+0200
DEA/186Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af2016-11-18T10:18:41.744+0200
API/5App instance exited with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af", "version"=>"948e02de-d579-4058-8e89-8573af7ca886", "instance"=>"0c345d386b924d949255d7a8de0482bc", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1479457067}2016-11-18T10:17:47.179+0200
DEA/133Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af2016-11-18T10:17:41.725+0200
API/9App instance exited with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af", "version"=>"948e02de-d579-4058-8e89-8573af7ca886", "instance"=>"7a8caf7bea6b4de6a45cce7cdc601ded", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1479457006}2016-11-18T10:16:46.720+0200
DEA/201Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af2016-11-18T10:16:41.710+0200
API/3App instance exited with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af", "version"=>"948e02de-d579-4058-8e89-8573af7ca886", "instance"=>"af4e6ebb4787454b99fdbedef268f5e9", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1479456961}2016-11-18T10:16:01.387+0200
DEA/145Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af2016-11-18T10:15:55.778+0200
API/0Updated app with guid 3ae2d9a1-28d9-47af-a7b4-2e311bd763af ({"state"=>"STARTED"})

Comment: You should remove your api_key before posting questions to stack overflow.  Now that it has been posted here, you should request a new api key.

Comment: Can you post your logs?

Comment: @DanielGrim I'll make sure to hide it next time, thanks a lot

Comment: @JeffSloyer posted the logs, I have no idea how to format them. I hope you can make something out of them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix is running a health check on your app which expects it to be listening on a port specified by the `$PORT` environment variable.  Because your app is not listening no this port, and also because it finishes executing and exits, Bluemix thinks that your app has crashed and that is why it shows as failing to start.

If you run `cf logs <app name> --recent`, replacing `<app name>` with the name of your application, you should see the output from your `print` statements in the logs.

If you want to run this type of application on Bluemix, you can use `cf push <app name> --no-route` to specify that the application will not be listening on the port specified in the `$PORT` environment variable.  You would also need to modify the code in some way to ensure that it continues running after these print statements have executed (ex: add an infinite loop at the end).  This will allow Bluemix to see your app as being in a running state, and the output from the app will be available from the `cf logs <app name> --recent` command.

Comment: Tried running it with --no-route still the same problem. Also cf logs <app name> --recent gives me "Error dialing trafficcontroller server" so i can't get the logs this way. The only way to get the logs is from inside the app in bluemix.

Comment: The error logs you posted are just displaying the app crashing every time it tries to start, there might be some more useful information further back in the logs right after the staging task finished.